# MS SQL: Suppress return value of stored procedure called in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, nocount

I think I have the same problem as kcrumley describes in the question "[Problem calling stored procedure from another stored procedure via classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107585/problem-calling-stored-procedure-from-another-stored-procedure-via-classic-asp)". However his question does not really include an solution, so I'll give it another shot, adding my own observations:

I have two stored procedures:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE return_1 AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1
END

CREATE PROCEDURE call_return_1_and_return_2 AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    EXEC return_1
    SELECT 2
END
```

Note that both procedures contain "SET NOCOUNT ON". When I execute "call_return_1_and_return_2" I still get two record sets. First the value 1, then the value 2.

That throws ASP (classic VBScript ASP) off the tracks.

Any hints on how I can suppress the first result set? Why is it there even with NOCOUNT?

Skipping the first record set in ASP is not an option. I need a "database only" solution.

Comment: A couple of responses are pointing out that you can change from a SELECT to a RETURN, but this is a great question - what if the nested stored proc has to SELECT, because something else calls it, and you can't change it? I wonder if it's possible to "swallow" a result set like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not the NOCOUNT thats causing this, your stored procedures have a select each so each one is coming in its own result set. This could be avoided by changing your first stored procedure to use output parameters to pass the number 1 back rather than doing a select. The second stored procedure could then examine the output parameter to get the data it needs to run.

Try something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
(
    @RetVal INT OUTPUT
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @RetVal = 1
```

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @RetVal int
EXEC    [dbo].[Proc1]
        @RetVal = @RetVal OUTPUT
SELECT  @RetVal as N'@RetVal'
```

Answer (score 17):

As Matt points out in his comment, neither solution really 'swallow' the first resultset.
I don't know why you'd want this but you can 'swallow' the result of the first exec by using a table variable. It must match the exact amount and type of the result set's columns. Like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE return_1 AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT 1
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE call_return_1_and_return_2 AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Result TABLE (res int)
    insert into @Result EXEC return_1
    SELECT 2
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are not return variables, but output record sets. I guess that as soon as SQL server flushes output to client, you're screwed and can't take it back.

I would solve this by adding a parameter to SP return_1, that would control if return_1 would select records or just do stuff and silently exit.